MacOS: Numbers export CSV line endings
Using Numbers 13.0 on MacOS.
When I export my table to CSV format, the generated file has strangly CRLF line endings. How can I teach Numbers to use normal LF line endings instead?
It is cumbersome and error prone, to always run a dos2unix after the data has been exported.

In case this is not configurable within Numbers, there is always the option of using Folder Actions to automatically convert CSV files.

In the end, since this can’t be changed, are you aware there are excellent automation tools to process a file you dump in a folder and optionally ask you where it needs to go? Hazel, folder actions with AppleScript JS automation, other scripting languages?

+1 for Hazel, the file Swiss Army Knife!

@user1934428 Normal for Unix.  The Mac in its history has used CR as a line ending.

@nohillside : Never heard of "Folder Actions". I will research into this topic....

@MarcWilson : I know, but these beasts don't have just CR, they have both, CRLF. Plus, MacOS is based on BSD Unix, where LF is the usual line separator now.

Numbers seems to be following the MIME/RFC 4180 standard which actually requires the CR/LF endings.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#RFC_4180_and_MIME_standards
